# Connect aws lambda to oracle rds gives time out

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, python-3.7

I am trying to connect lambda function to oracle rds using below code but getting timeout.
My lambda function is in same vpc as rds and it is also attached with same security group as rds, i also allowed vpc cide in sg. I created an ec2 instance to download oracle libraries and client, zip those and put them into s3 and then created lambda layer for the function. Can somene please let me know what am i missing. Cloudwatch logs also shows just timeout nothing else. If i put anything else in the host e.g any other random name, it gives me a different error "ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist". I am currently using oracle rds dns name which is shown in rds screen

```
 import json
 import boto3
 import os
 import cx_Oracle

def lambda_handler(event, context):

 
port = os.getenv('1521') # 1521
sid = os.getenv('SID') # ORCL
db_user = os.getenv('admin') # <user-id>
db_password = os.getenv('password') # <password


dsnStr = cx_Oracle.makedsn("host", "1521", "SID")
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user = db_user, password = db_password, dsn = dsnStr, encoding = 
'UTF-8')

c = conn.cursor()


return "Connection established with Oracle database"
```

Comment: try creating a new security group which allows all incoming connections from the security group id and attach it to both the lambda and the RDS. (It's not clear in your question if this is what you mean when you say you attached the same security group)

Comment: My comment is unrelated to your networking problem, but you may want to upgrade to the latest, renamed release of cx_Oracle (now called python-oracledb, see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a)) because you won't need to use Instant Client for most code.

Answer (score 0):

It should be Network side Problem check your security group please check the security group inbound rule and allow traffic from lambda function sg to oracle database sg. chek this it will be solve this issue

Comment: Thanks all for your replies, i realised the issue was around the memory used by lambda,when i increased the memory, i am not getting issues with timeout anymore but now i am getting invalid database username/password. I will confirm this and add to answer